# Installing brew with OS X issue

Tags: ruby, macos, unix, homebrew

When I try to install `brew` with the command

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I get the following error

> /Users/nouveau/.rbenv/shims/ruby: ligne21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `rbenv` installation seems to be broken. Just remove it:

```
cd
rm -rf rbenv
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar
exit # close terminal
```

Then repeat homebrew installation (with your system Ruby):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```